# Can threads of a process made run on different CPUS

Tags: linux, bash, multithreading

Would like to know, if thread of a process can be made to run on different set of CPU's in Linux?
For instance, let's say we start a process with 30 threads then first 15 threads from this process is made to run on core 0-14 using taskset program, and rest of threads on core 15-29?

Is above configuration possible?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html

Comment: General entry point [man sched](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html). Note that you can find this stuff by reading the manpage for `taskset`, which you already know about. It's in the **See Also** section at the bottom.

Comment: Okay, I just removed the "C" from tag, as looking to achieve this using already existing tools from shell script.

Comment: You can do what @JJF suggested, buy why? The goal of the scheduler in pretty much any mainstream Linux distro will be to make the best possible use of the host's CPUs. It won't allow a CPU to sit idle when there is a thread that is ready to run. If your application is the only thing running on the box, and if it has multiple threads that are ready-to-run, then it's virtually guaranteed that all of the box's CPUs will serve your application most of the time. Is your question, maybe an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?